# How to make a table in C using loops

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How do you make a table like the pic (you are using the ideal gas law). The volume values should start on the left-most column with the start volume and increase in equal steps
such that the right-most column's volume is the stop volume. For each entry in the table, compute the pressure at the given temperature and volume, Please help.

Volume: 10.00 --- 18.89 --- 27.78 --- 36.67

Temp:

300.00 - 24.94 --- 13.20 --- 8.98 --- 6.80

400.00 - 33.26 --- 17.61 ---11.97--- 9.07

500.00 - 41.57 --- 22.01 ---14.97--- 11.34

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
float vol1, vol2;
float temp1, temp2;
float R = 8.314;
int mole;
int rows;
int columns = 8;



printf("Enter the starting volume (in meters cubed):");
scanf("%f",&vol1);
while(vol1<0)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a number that is positive:");
    scanf("%f",&vol1);
}

printf("Enter the ending volume (in meters cubed):");
scanf("%f",&vol2);
while(vol2<0)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a number that is positive:");
    scanf("%f",&vol2);
}

printf("Next enter the starting temperature (in kelvin):");
scanf("%f",&temp1);
while(temp1<0)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a number that is positive:");
    scanf("%f",&temp1);
}
printf("Enter the ending temperature (in kelvin):");
scanf("%f",&temp2);
while(temp2<0)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a number that is positive:");
    scanf("%f",&temp2);
}
printf("Enter the number of moles:");
scanf("%f",&mole);
while(mole<0)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a number that is positive:");
    scanf("%f",&mole);
}

printf("How many rows should the temperature value have?\n");
scanf("%d",&rows);
while(rows<1)
{
    printf("Error: Enter a number that is positive:");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
}






return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Give more specifics, what you want us to do ( I cannot understand your table ).

Comment: Why are you prompting for values instead of having the user pass them in as arguments?   This is a very unnatural interface.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're asking, so I'll reword your question so it is clear. You are trying to print out a 2D table with values that change in equal steps in the x direction (volume in this case) and equal values in the y direction (temperature in this case). I think that vol1 is starting volume and vol 2 is ending volume? and same for tmeperature?

The key to doing this is to use nested for loops

So something like this

```
for (x=vol1; x<vol2; x + volstepsize)
{
    for(y=temp1; y<temp2; y + tempstepsize)
    {
       compute gas law equation here using x and y and do a print statement
    }
  perform a blank print line statement here to indent/start the next row
}
```

By having nested for loops you will print out row and column sequentially; this is a fundamental concept for accessing and writing 2D tables.

Hope that helps!